# Parallel merge sort useing _beginthreadex windows API in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort using win32 _beginthreadex multiple threads in c++. basically it uses _beginthreadex instead of function call to make recursion in each thread. so it will has as many threads as possible. the while loop after the two _beginthreadex call is to check if the children threads finish there job. But when the program access the array a and b, it gives an error that unable to read the memory, I can't find what the problem is. It seems that in the sorting section in children threads the program try to access invalid memory address that info->b goes to the address 0xcccccccc {???} 
Thank you

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


struct ThreadInfo
{
    int* a;
    int* b;
    int low;
    int high;
    bool run;
};





unsigned __stdcall mergesort(void* x) {

ThreadInfo* info = (ThreadInfo*)x;

if ((info->low) < (info->high))
{
    int pivot = ((info->low)+(info->high))/2;
    ThreadInfo lowInfo;
    ThreadInfo highInfo;
    lowInfo.a=info->a;
    lowInfo.low=info->low;
    lowInfo.high=pivot;
    lowInfo.run=true;
    highInfo.b=info->b;
    highInfo.low=pivot+1;
    highInfo.high=info->high;
    highInfo.run=true;
    //HANDLE myhandlerUp, myhandlerDown;


    //creat sub-thread
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, mergesort, &lowInfo, 0, 0);
    //WaitForSingleObject(myhandlerUp,INFINITE);
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, mergesort, &highInfo, 0, 0);
    //WaitForSingleObject(myhandlerDown,INFINITE);
    //check if any child threads are working 



    bool anyRun = true;
    while (anyRun)
    {
        anyRun = false;
        anyRun = lowInfo.run || highInfo.run;

    }

    //doing merge sort
    int h,i,j,k,low, high;
    low = info->low;
    high = info->high;
    h=low;
    i=low;
    j=pivot+1;
    while((h<=pivot)&&(j<=high))
     {

         if(info->a[h]<=info->a[j])
         {
             info->b[i]=info->a[h];
             h++;
         }
         else
         {
             info->b[i]=info->a[j];
             j++;
          }
          i++;
     }


    if(h>pivot)
    {
        for(k=j; k<=high; k++)
        {
            info->b[i]=info->a[k];
            i++;
        }
     }


    else
    {
        for(k=h; k<=pivot; k++)
           {
               info->b[i]=info->a[k];
               i++;
           }
    }

        for(k=low; k<=high; k++) info->a[k]=info->b[k];

    }


    info->run = false;
    return 0;

}

void main()
{

ThreadInfo info;
int inputArr[12] = {12,10,43,23,-78,45,123,56,98,41,90,24};


int copiedArr[12]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
info.a=inputArr;
info.b=copiedArr;

for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
cout<<info.a[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;


info.low=0;
info.high=(11);
info.run=true;
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, mergesort, &info, 0, 0);



bool finish = info.run;
while(finish){
    cout<<"Running...."<<endl;
    Sleep(1000);
}



cout<<"After run the result is "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    cout<<inputArr[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;

getchar();

}
```

Comment: I think [reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130307/performance-problems-in-parallel-mergesort-c/24134200#24134200) may open a few doors and ideas. seriously. take the time.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it doesn't improve performance, there are serious issues with your code. Firstly, it is not indented, doesn't check for errors, is littered with magic numbers, uses C-style casts unnecessarily. That's what makes the code nasty to work with. Then, there is no synchronization between threads, which is inviting race conditions. Lastly, you are passing addresses of local variables to other threads and then exit the function, which is probably what's killing you. BTW: Consider using std::thread, if your compiler supports it!