# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurring when running recursive merge sort method in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, recursion

I'm having trouble with my C++ code in xCode. I've tried debugging and I can't fix it. I know it's roughly when my mergeSort() method calls my mergeNumbers() method. I know it's not the method itself because I've run the method without threading and it works just fine. It's when I try to use it in the thread that I'm getting a problem.

I tried looking online and the closest thing I could find to my problem was that it may be a problem with my method calling an object that was deleted or no longer exists. I would appreciate any feedback on this. Thank you.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
void openFile();
void* mergeSort(void *threadid);
void mergeNumbers(int *myArray, int minCount, int maxCount, int midCount);
void mergeSort(int *myArray, int minCount, int maxCount);
void trial2();

int array1[500000];
int array2[500000];
int array3[250000];
int array4[250000];
int array5[250000];
int array6[250000];


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    openFile();
    //trial1();
    trial2();
    return 0; 
}

void trial2(){
    int i, t1;
    void *status;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
    t1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, mergeSort, (void *)i);
    pthread_join(thread1, &status);
}

void* mergeSort(void *threadid){
    long tid = (long)threadid;
    cout << "I am performing the Merge Sort" << endl;
    mergeSort(array6, 0, 249999);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void mergeSort(int *myArray, int minCount, int maxCount)
{
    int midCount;
    if (minCount < maxCount)
    {
        midCount=(minCount+maxCount)/2;
        mergeSort(myArray,minCount,midCount);
        mergeSort(myArray,midCount + 1,maxCount);

        mergeNumbers(myArray, minCount, maxCount, midCount);
    }
    return;
}

void mergeNumbers(int *myArray, int minCount, int maxCount, int midCount)
{
    int newArray[maxCount + 1];
    int arrayNum = minCount;
    int num1 = minCount;
    int num2 = midCount + 1;


    while (num1 <= midCount && num2 <= maxCount)
    {
        if (myArray[num1] < myArray[num2])
        {
            newArray[arrayNum] = myArray[num1];
            num1++;
            arrayNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[arrayNum] = myArray[num2];
            num2++;
            arrayNum++;
        }
    }

    while (num1 <= midCount)
    {
        newArray[arrayNum] = myArray[num1];
        num1++;
        arrayNum++;
    }

    while (num2 <= maxCount)
    {
        newArray[arrayNum] = myArray[num2];
        num2++;
        arrayNum++;
    }

    for (num1 = minCount; num1 < arrayNum; num1++)
    {
        myArray[num1] = newArray[num1];
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is:      Thread2:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address = 0x1007d2be0).

Comment: `int newArray[maxCount + 1];` is going to allocate a merge-bed of 250,000 `int` on the stack, roughly 1MB for 32bit values, If your thread's stack isn't capable of handling that, you're going to overflow. is there some reason you're not using dynamic allocation for this? Regarding parallelizing mergsort in general, you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24134200/1322972) interesting.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem. I didn't think about that problem at all.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for following through and selecting the most-appropriate (and in this case only) answer.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem originates in this line:

```
int newArray[maxCount + 1];
```

You are trying to allocate ~250000 `int`s on the stack (on most 32 bit platforms it will take ~`1MB` of memory). Your thread's stack may not be able to do this.

By the way, you should not do this - creating arrays of size known at runtime should be done via heap memory allocation:

```
int* newArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (maxCount + 1));
```

and at the end of the function:

```
free(newArray);
```

The best solution, however, would be to use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

Comment: Note: the more optimal solution would be a RAII construct like `std::vector<>` (uptick, btw), but one that does *not* value-initialize the content, as it is about to be obliterated by the merge anyway. There is no need to zero-fill a container you're about to overwrite regardless. `std::unique_ptr<int[]> ar(new int[maxCount+1]);` is one such example.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Your comments have helped a lot. :)