# Merging 2 quick sorted arrays results in all 0s

Tags: c, multithreading, merge, quicksort

I am using a multithreaded program to sort an array. First I split the array into 2 halves. 1 thread sorts the first half, another thread sorts the second half, and the last thread merges the two halves together. I use quick sort to sort each of the halves. The problem is, when I print the sorted array it is just 0s.

I've been using print statements to check the contents of the arrays. Initially, quick sort seemed to be working, but now I'm getting the correct array but with extra numbers added on. I'm thinking the issue could be memory being overwritten, but I'm really not sure so I'm including more code than may be necessary.

*note: mainarr is a global variable declared as: `int *mainarr`

```
//function to merge two halves in result array
void merge(int l[], int r[], int size_left, int size_right)
{
    //iterator variables, start at 0
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // Traverse both array
    while (i < size_left && j < size_right)
    {
        if (l[i] < r[j]){
            mainarr[k] = l[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            mainarr[k] = r[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    // Store remaining elements of first array
    while (i < size_left){
        mainarr[k] = l[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    // Store remaining elements of second array
    while (j < size_right){
        mainarr[k] = r[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

//compare function for qsort
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

//thread begins control in this function
//this function is called from pthread_create
void *runner(void* param) {
    int threadID = atoi(param);
    int midpoint = size/2, index, r;
    int *left = malloc(midpoint*sizeof(int));
    int *right = malloc((size-midpoint)*sizeof(int));

    //if first thread, sort "left" array
    if(threadID == 1){
        int i;
        index=0;
        //create "left" array
        for(i=0; i < midpoint; i++){
            left[index] = mainarr[i];
            index++;
        }
        //sort array
        qsort(left, midpoint, sizeof(int), compare);
        printf("LEFT array: ");
        for(r = 0; r < size; r++)
            printf("%d ", left[r]);
    }
    //if second thread, sort "right" array
    else if(threadID == 2){
        int j;
        index=0;
        //create "right" array
        for(j=midpoint; j < size; j++){
            right[index] = mainarr[j];
            index++;
        }
        //sort array
        qsort(right, (size-midpoint), sizeof(int), compare);
        printf("RIGHT array: ");
        for(r = 0; r < size; r++)
            printf("%d ", right[r]);
    }
    //if third thread, merge the left and right arrays
    else if(threadID == 3){
        merge(left, right, 4, 5);
    }

    //empty else to satisfy convention
    else{}

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The example I've been using is the array `[7,0,2,33,234,1,3,67,54]`. So, I expect the sorted "left" array to be `[0,2,7,33]`, the sorted "right" array to be `[1,3,54,67,234]`, and the whole sorted array to be `[0,1,2,3,7,33,54,67,234]`. However, the actual sorted "left" array is `[0, 2, 7, 33, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0]`, the actual sorted "right" array is `[1, 3, 54, 67, 234, 0, 132881, 0, 0]`, and the actual whole sorted array is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I'm not sure what the issue is - whether it's the threads, memory overwriting itself, or something else. Anything helps, thank you.

UPDATE/SOLUTION: I am mallocing left and right outside of the if statements, so when a new thread starts it clears the contents of the left and right arrays leading to a result of all 0s.

Comment: Not to sound self-serving, you really might find [this interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130307/performance-problems-in-parallel-mergesort-c/24134200#24134200). It's for C++, but the idea is the same in C.

Comment: Regardless, your merge routine at least appears to be correct (seemingly). What is *not* apparent is the usage of `mainarr`, which I suspect is where your problem is. If it doesn't change for the lifetime of this you're screwed; Both the top and bottom partitions will attempt to write to `mainarr` starting at offset 0. Furthermore, the third thread is useless and actually making things worse. You can't merge left and right sides until thy're sorted, which means means you have to wait for both child partitions to finish before merging to the common parent. All of that said, how about a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

> However, the actual sorted "left" array is [0, 2, 7, 33, 0, 0, 37, 0,
>   0],

No, it isn't.

> the actual sorted "right" array is [1, 3, 54, 67, 234, 0, 132881,
>   0, 0]

No, it isn't.

You are printing elements beyond the allocated bounds of those arrays.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  You are (un)lucky that the program doesn't just crash.  Note that the values within the actual bounds of those arrays are as you expected.

> the actual whole sorted array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Sort of.

I can believe that that's what's printed, since you're merging two arrays allocated by the third thread and whose contents are never set.  The behavior here is again undefined, and there's no reason at all to expect that the third thread will see the sorted results from the other two threads when each thread allocates its own, separate, pairs of sub-arrays (and leaks them).

I don't actually see the point of a separate merge thread.  The merge cannot be performed until the two quicksort threads complete, and since it cannot run concurrently with the others, I see no reason not to leave that work for the main thread.  Overall, I suggest this:

- One (new) thread each for quicksorting the two array halves.  Alternatively, a single new thread for one half, and the main thread handles the other.
- Perform standard in-place quicksort instead of having the threads perform any memory allocation or copying to temp space.
- After the main thread joins the other(s), it performs the merge itself.